# Restrict a C++ template type to a specific variable size

Tags: c++, templates

I was wondering if it is possible to restrict a template type to be a variable type of a specific size?
Assuming I want to accept 4-bytes variable and rejects all the others, if running this code on some compiler where sizeof(int) == 4 and sizeof(bool) == 1:

```
template <class T> FourOnly {...};
FourOnly<int> myInt; // this should compile
FourOnly<bool> myBool; // this should fail at compilation time
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for an answer to something you "think" is the solution to a deeper problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: @Zadirion I was implementing an obfuscated int variable (a int that is de/obfuscated on the fly every time it's used, but it's stored as obfuscated on the heap). The obfuscation is basically just shuffling the bits around with some bit masks and shifting. I was trying to create a template to apply that to every primitive type with the same size (so I could use the same shuffling masks).

Comment: aaaah, interesting! Interesting use case, might come in handy :D +1 !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a static assertion:

```
template <class T> FourOnly 
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T)==4, "T is not 4 bytes");
};
```

If you don't have the relevant C++11 support, you could have a look at [boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

Comment: * available starting with C++11.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::enable_if` to disallow compilation when `sizeof(T)` is not 4.

```
template<typename T,
         typename _ = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T)==4>::type
        >
struct Four
{};
```

However, I'd prefer the `static_assert` solution in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503578/241631).

Comment: Thanks for your time. The other answer mentions being available starting with C++11, what about this solution?

Comment: I'm not sure whether `enable_if` is available under the `tr1` namespace for pre-C++11 compilers. But it is available from Boost.

Comment: @Marco83 the same applies, although there is [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), which has basically the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Well, as you said yourself that you prefer the other answer, I'm gonna select that one :)

Comment: Looks good, but compilation _is possible_, if we will pass second template argument. So, I would prefer to `using _ = typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) == 4, void>::type;` inside a class.